# Error 500 internal server error when sending post http request using Guzzle

Tags: php, http, http-post, guzzle, http-status-code-500

I am trying to send an post http request using Guzzle but i got error 500

```
Internal server error 
ServerException in RequestException.php line 113:
Server error: `POST https://domainname/api/v1/user/register` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofo (truncated...)
```

I tried to send the same header and body keys using Postman , it worked without any issue :

```
{
    "status": "true"
}
```

Header:
[image]
Body:
[image]

This is my Guzzle client request :-

```
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://domainname/api/v1/']);
                   $response = $client->request('POST', 'user/register', [
                       'headers' => [
                           'Authorization' => Session::get('token'),
                           'Content-Type'     => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                       ],
                       'form_params' => [
                           'start_date' => $start_date,
                           'expiry_date' => $expiry_date,
                           'type' => 'normal',
                           'status' => 'active',

                       ]
                   ]);

                    $response= $response->getBody();
                    $re= json_decode($response);
```

My route to that api:-

```
Route::post('/user/register', 'UsersAPI@register');
```

My Register controller :

```
public function register(Request $request){
Log::info('Request: ' . $request);
//dd($request->all());
     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        // 'user_id' => 'required',
        'start_date' => 'required',
        'expiry_date' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'status'=>'required',   
        //'receipt' => 'required',
        //'purchase_id'=>'required',
    ]);

    $user = JWTAuth::toUser(); 
      //Check whether validation is failed or passed
    if($validator->fails()){
        //Redirect back with validation errors
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 400);
    }



         $user = new User($data);
        $user->user()->save($user);
     Log::info('save_user done for this user: ' . $user->id);


    return ['status' => 'true']; 
}
```

NGINX error.log :-

```
[02/Dec/2017:15:49:13 +0300] "POST /api/v1/user/register HTTP/1.1" 500 16904 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.55.0 PHP/7.1.9"
```

Comment: In your Postman I can see you're missing space for Authorization header, between "Bearer" and the token itself. By that, take a look at the value of Session::get('token'). 

BTW Error 500 can mean anything. You need to deep and figure out the real problem. This log output is not so useful.

Comment: @Dusan Yes you are right, i just tried with replacing the variables in request with 'string' , it worked without returning error .

Answer (score 0):

If the same code produces different results depending on how you send your request, I would assume there are still differences between the request payloads.

Have you double-checked the contents of Session::get('token'), $start_date and $expiry_date?

Comment: Yes you are right, i just tried with replacing the variables in request with 'string' , it worked without returning error . the problem is in $dates not session('token') i will try to figure what is the problem

Comment: I have the following variables for $date ..... $start_date = Carbon::now();
        $expiry_date = Carbon::now()->addDays(30); why they are producing an error 500 ?

Comment: echo $start_date ==> 2017-12-02 14:16:16; echo $expiry_date ==> 
2018-01-01 14:16:16

Comment: Usually the 500 response has a root cause that can be logged somehow. What does the server log say where the controller code is located? Since you don't have code in the controller that outputs a 500 status code explicitly, I assume that some kind of exception is thrown. If you don't already see a conclusive error message in your log, try and wrap your code in a try...catch block, catch all \Exception instances and output/log the exception message. That should give you a hint.

Comment: this is strange issue, when i just replace the 'start_date' => $start_date, 'expiry_date' => $expiry_date, with 'start_date' => '2017-12-1 14:06:58','expiry_date' => '2017-12-20 14:06:58', The request work without any issue, even i am using the datetime format i got from the both variables, regarding the log for error 500 i posted what i got in Nginx server, please see my main question post

Comment: Well, then I'd assume that the call to Carbon::now() is the issue. Have you tried wrapping it in a try..catch block and logging the exception message, if there is one?